# Que signifie l'expression "ne bander que d'une" ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour,

Savez-vous, s'il vous plaît, ce que signifie l'expression ***ne* *bander que d'une*** dans ce cas?

"Ah! Il se marrait tout de même au fond!... On voyait bien qu'il taquinait... qu'il nous faisait marcher... Croquemitaine!... Coquin de nature!... Malgré tout, j'étais pas certain... **je bandais que d'une!**..." (CÉLINE, 2015, p. 170)

J'imagine, par le contexte, qu'il s'agit d'une expression pour exprimer la peur, mais comment le sens sexuel a-t-il pu être tellement dérivé ?

Comment: (CÉLINE, 2015, p. 170) Cela se trouve où?

Comment: Dans Guignol's Band I, l'édition de la Pléiade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jacques Cellard dans *[Ça mange pas de pain: 400 expressions familières ou voyoutes de France et du Québec](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ddVXDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT170&lpg=PT170&dq=%22bander%20que%20d%27une%22&source=bl&ots=41w0gRPrXq&sig=ACfU3U0xXPTGMLKWLQQUsJlhY10s7qTURg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiowf30jKnyAhXyA2MBHQeQB8cQ6AF6BAgTEAM#v=onepage&q=%22bander%20que%20d%27une%22&f=false)* :

**Ne bander que d'une**

Être effrayé, avoir peur, redouter un accident fatal. Être plus ou moins paralysé par la peur.
Le courage et la lâcheté sont traduits par les deux expressions parallèles : *avoir* (*ou ne pas avoir*) *de couilles au cul*, « être foncièrement courageux, ou lâche ». Entre les deux, *ne bander que d'une* (couille) exprime l'idée d'une appréhension momentanée face au danger. L'assimilation du courage physique à la virilité sexuelle n'est que symbolique, rien ne prouvant que les héros de Mars le soient aussi de Vénus.

> *Elle s'est lancée en équilibre sur la solive en suspens ... Je lui tenais, moi, la main ... d'en haut ... Je bandais que d'une de la voir branler au-dessus du gouffre ...*(L.-F. Céline, *Mort à crédit*. p.965)